# Contemporary equivalent of the word "moxie" as defined herein

Tags: single-word-requests, slang, personality

I'm fiddling around with a piece of prose that my other half once wrote, trying to get it translated to English.

The text is basically an inner monologue. After a burst of (verbal) aggressiveness, the "inner" speaker gradually gets hold of himself/herself, and despite the fairly reasonable content of what has been said, he/she is left with a certain sense of remorse due to the severeness of his/her manners.

At that point he/she says something like:

> -A stupid *grit* is all that's left...

Now, that was just my very first attempt to render the sentence; but I know that *grit* [courage and resolve; strength of character (Oxford D.)] isn't quite the word I'm looking for. It's just familiar enough to be used without noticeable hesitation.

I asked a reliable elder for a piece of cyber-advice and he recommended *foolish bravado*.

I objected, saying that "bravado" gives me the impression of a slightly masculine word, whereas I'm looking for something unisex, so to speak. Eventually I got convinced my impression was wrong, but "bravado" still sounds a bit "cowboy" in my (European) ears, probably due to its phonetic resemblance to Rio Bravo and its overall Spanish/Mexican features.

For now, I've changed *grit* to *chutzpah*, meaning "extreme self-confidence or audacity" (again, according to Oxford D.).

But whereas *grit* was a bit too close to *courage* (which can hardly be a bad thing), *chutzpah* seems to be at the other end of the spectrum, connoting excessiveness (which is rarely a good thing).

I felt I'd like something more ambiguous. So I eventually stumbled upon this word:

> mox·ie  (mŏk′sē)
>   n. Slang
>   1. The ability to face difficulty with spirit and courage.
>   2. Aggressive energy; initiative:
>   3. Skill; know-how.

Macmillan is more concise about it: `energy, confidence, and determination.`
It *does* however tell you that apart from being slang, the word is also old-fashioned.

And I wouldn't want to use outdated language.

The triplet of possible interpretations *does*, however, serve my intentions perfectly, *aggressive energy (2)* being a potential downside of an overall courageous character...

Thus comes my question: what would be an accurate modern equivalent of the word *moxie*, able to connote all three aforementioned aspects of someone's personality?

And I'm not looking for anything offensive, like b@ll$ or whatever. Just a pertinent word one might hear "on the street", with a fair share of potential to fit in this sentence:

*A stupid ***** is all that's left*.
(kinda muttered in a state of confusion; a stalemate between pride and remorse).

Comment: Did you not consider _aggression_ (you used _aggressiveness_ in your question)?

Comment: Well, I personally really like the word *chutzpah*, but I don't see how any of these words you proposed fit in the sentence.

Comment: I like "grit" because of its multiple, intentionally vague meanings in this intentionally uncertain context, including the grade (coarseness) of sandpaper, gritting one's teeth (in irritation or stoic silence), stray bits of sand encountered in a foodstuff (a dreadful sensation of grit), as well as the possibility of so-called "True Grit" (John Wayne, 1969; Jeff Bridges, 2010; Charles Portis' novel, 1968), etc. That is, unless you want to infuse a Yiddish flavor, of course, then chutzpah seems closer than moxie. It's all up to you. "A stupid *grit* is all that's left" works perfectly for me.

Comment: @aparente001 Well I _have_ tried to explain my context as thoroughly as possible. That said, the fact remains that the text is a literary one and a certain looseness of expression must be licensed. Still, I _may_ understand that _grit_ doesn't quite qualify after such an adjective as _stupid_, but _chutzpah_? I've read foreign affairs columnists criticizing Israel of its stupid chutzpah, but I guess this kind of usage appeared posterior to descriptions of individuals, no? As for _moxie_, yes, it was somewhat of an experiment, but judging from the answer below, it did get the message through.

Comment: *Stupid feistiness* works for me.  (I googled the exact phrase "stupid chutzpah," and from the quick glance I took, I think those who said it were using *stupid* to mean *goddamn*.  Maybe that's what you meant, too.  I don't think *ballsiness* can be classified as either intelligent or unintelligent.  You're either ballsy or you're not!  Just my personal opinion.)

Comment: I think you should consider replacing both the noun (_moxie_ or whatever) and the modifier (_stupid_ or _foolish_), since neither of those adjectives seems especially apt for the context you describe. I would aim more in the direction of a phrase like "residue of departed aggression" to get at the bad aftertaste that the flare of vehement speech has left the speaker with.

Comment: @SvenYargs Eloquent as many of these comments may be, the same is not meant to apply for my character. I'm deliberately looking for a word that he/she mutters for himself/herself, and that may not really convey as accurately as possible his/her state at the very time of speaking but is still quite telling with regards to his overall character... Anyways, I'm being vague, I know...

Comment: Regarding the old-fashionedness of *Moxie* : I just heard the phrase *that took moxie!* on Cartoon Network's *Mighty Magiswords* (yes, it's the holidays, and I'm stuck watching cartoons with middle schoolers). So if you really like that word, I wouldn't rule it out.

Answer (score 1):

A stupid ***feistiness*** is all that is left.  Feistiness is the state of being feisty, which is defined in the [Cambridge English Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/feisty) as:

> active, forceful and determined; Example: She’s a feisty kid who is
>   not afraid to challenge authority

The [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/feisty) says in its first definition that feistiness is typically used for someone relatively small:

> 1. (of a person, typically one who is relatively small) lively,  determined, and courageous:    ‘a love story with a feisty heroine
>      who's more than a pretty face’
>
> 1.1. Touchy and aggressive:
>
> ‘he got a bit feisty and tried to hit me’

Feisty people are often punching above their weight, and can be successful doing so, particularly if they have good judgment.  Your character sounds as though he/she is struggling with the consequences of a lapse of judgment.

Comment: This sounds like a near perfect answer. The adjective does, however, sound a bit more casual than the noun. Is _feistiness_ a word you'll hear "on the street", so to speak? (The Internet has basically been my only means of contact with the English language for quite some time now, so I'm a bit clueless, "register-wise"..)

Comment: My view of the street is pretty limited too.  Feisty and feistiness are not words I've heard spoken often and I doubt they are the latest "in" words.  Without knowing more about your character, his/her surroundings and social class, it's hard to say whether feistiness would be often heard on the streets they frequent.  But these are not rare words.